# Use multiple expression in grepl string to create new data

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when, grepl

I would like to create a new column based on the string in another column in my data frame. Using `case_when` and `grepl` I would like to make a new class if string contains `value1` OR `value2`. But, not sure how to put there this 'OR' statement?

Dummy example (not working):

```
df <- data.frame(type = "a_m5", "a_m20", "a_5")

df %>% 
  mutate(modif = case_when(
    grepl('_m5'|'_m20', type) ~ 'less', # how to specify here | OR symbol in R? 
    grepl('_5', type) ~ 'more'))
```

Of course, it works if I specify the statements one by one (working):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(modif = case_when(
    grepl('_m5', type) ~ 'less',
    grepl('_m20', type) ~ 'less',
    grepl('_5', type) ~ 'more'))
```

but I wonder how to make it one line, as I have multiple options? maybe something like `chars %in% vector` would work here?

Desired output:

```
   type modif
1  a_m5  less
2 a_m20  less
3   a_5  more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `%in%` here:

```r
df %>% 
    mutate(modif = case_when(
        type %in% c('_m5', '_m20') ~ 'less',
        TRUE ~ 'more')
    )
```

You could also keep one value on the LHS per predicate, to keep it consistent:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(modif = case_when(
        '_m5' ~ 'less',
        '_m20' ~ 'less',
        TRUE ~ 'more')
    )
```

Note that I don't bother explicitly checking for a `_5` value, assuming that it would be the only other possible value.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can put `|` into your grepl regex expression:

```
df <- data.frame(type = c("a_m5", "a_m20", "a_5"))

df %>% 
  mutate(modif = case_when(
    grepl('_m5|_m20', type) ~ 'less',
    grepl('_5', type) ~ 'more'))

   type modif
1  a_m5  less
2 a_m20  less
3   a_5  more
```